# About print result output abnormal

Tags: python

I designed a small program
Calculate the call fee that should be paid based on your monthly fee type
And give you the discounts you can get
But my question is
After the output of my python program, more than one print is abnormally displayed?
Normally there should be only one print result

```
My code:
nus=input('Enter the monthly fee form and call time as:').split(',')
a1=int(nus[1])*0.09
if a1<=186:
       print('The call fee is: 186')
if a1<=186*2:
      a2=int(nus[1])*0.09*0.9
      print('Call fee is:',int(round(a2,1)))
if a1>186*2:
      a3=int(nus[1])*0.09*0.8
      print('Call fee is:',int(round(a3,1)))
      a4=int(nus[1])*0.08
if a4<=386:
       print('Call fee is: 386')
       if a4<=386*2:
        a5=int(nus[1])*0.08*0.8
       print('Call fee is:',int(round(a5,1)))
if a4>386*2:
          a6=int(nus[1])*0.08*0.7
          print('Call fee is:',int(round(a6,1)))
          a7=int(nus[1])*0.07
if a7<=586:
          print('Call fee is: 586')
if a7<=586*2:
       a8=int(nus[1])*0.07*0.7
       print('Call fee is:',int(round(a8,1)))
if a7>586*2:
      a9=int(nus[1])*0.07*0.6
      print('Call fee is:',int(round(a9,1)))
      e1=int(nus[1])*0.06
if e1<=986:
     print('Call fee is: 986')
if e1<=986*2:
       e2=int(nus[1])*0.06*0.6
       print('Call fee is:',int(round(e2,1)))
if e1>986*2:
         e3=int(nus[1])*0.06*0.5
         print('Call fee is:',int(round(e3,1)))

Abnormal result
enter
Enter the monthly fee form and call time: 386, 36000
Output
Call fee: 2592
The call fee is: 2016
Call fee: 1512
The call fee is: 1080



Normal result
Enter the monthly fee form and call time: 386, 36000
Output
The call fee is: 2016
```

Comment: The conditions you are testing are not mutually exclusive. That's why you have more than one print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's think of it with an example. Imagine I introduce a value such that a1 = 90. Then a1 <= 186 is true, so this is executed

```
print('The call fee is: 186')
```

However, a1 <= 186*2 is also true, so this is executed as well

```
a2=int(nus[1])*0.09*0.9
print('Call fee is:',int(round(a2,1)))
```

What you want to do is replace all the if conditions after the first one with elif. Elif means else + if, that is, if no previous condition has been satisfied previously, check if the current one is satisfied, otherwise skip. This will avoid entering multiple if clauses.

Comment: You are welcome! Please mark as solved if the issue is solved